# Zoom to feature by clicking cell in the Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, pyqgis-3, zoom

I have a layer which has `FID` field representing the unique ID of features. In QGIS, there is a `Zoom to selected rows` button on top of the Attribute Table. It has a shortcut (Ctrl + J) and it doesn't work (at least in my computer). (In ArcGIS, when you double-click a row number in the Attribute table, it zooms to related feature)

Sometimes, it's a waste of time to click the zoom button if considering hundreds of features and I need to speed up the zooming process to save time.

I can display the attribute table using the lines below and get the reference of it.

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYER_NAME")[0]
attr_table = iface.showAttributeTable(lyr)
```

Is there any programmatic way to zoom to a feature by clicking `FID` cell in the Attribute Table in QGIS? How can I add this capability to the Attribute Table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a temporary solution:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYER_NAME")[0]    
attr_table = iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
table = attr_table.findChildren(QTableView)[0]

def zoom(item):
    """ zooms to feature when clicking FID field """
    x = item.data() # get cell value
    try:
        ID = list(layer.getFeatures('"FID" = ' + x))[0].id()
        iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFeatureIds(layer, [ID])
    # when clicked another/wrong cell, it may throw an error, pass the error.
    except: 
        pass

table.clicked.connect(zoom) # attach zoom method to click event of the table
```

`showAttributeTable` returns the reference of the attribute table, and the attribute table contains only one `QTableView` element which is the object containing all columns and rows. Then, when clicked `FID` value/cell, it zooms to feature with `FID` value.

In that script, **the main limitation** is that I have to open the attribute table using `showAttributeTable` method. If I open the table using `Right click -> Open Attribute Table`, clicking `FID` value doesn't work. Also, when I close the attribute table, `attr_table` and `table` objects are deleted. It means that every time I open the table, new objects are created.

[image]