# Modify Attribute Table while opening using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, pyqgis-3

I have a problem related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/343241/29431) and the script given as the answer. I can add some functionalities to Attribute Table (**AT**) by the script in the post. But according to the post, I have to open the AT using `showAttributeTable` method, because the method returns the reference of the AT created/opened.

Of course, I can get references of all opened ATs using the following line.

```py
tables = [w for w in qApp.allWidgets() if w.objectName() == 'AttributeTable']
```

Let's say, I want to add a button to all ATs to be opened or sort by a column for a specific layer. Somehow, I think I need to catch "the AT's opening event" or "a widget/child was added to `iface.mainWindow()`" etc.

I have looked at [Qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/) and QGIS API([QgsApplication](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html)) documentation, but I couldn't find anything helpful or I missed something.

A pseudo code for a possible solution:

```py
def something_opened(something):
    if something is an attribute_table and active_layer is foo_bar:
        do something

main_window.addedsomething.connect(something_opened)
```

---

**Note**: @Ben's answer is pretty nice. But, it still requires me to focus on the AT.

Answer (score 15):

Interesting question! I couldn't find any native signal emitted when an attribute table is opened or closed so I would call this solution a fairly inelegant workaround but it seems to work well enough. I found that `QApplication` has a `focusChanged(old, new)` signal which is emitted whenever the widget focus changes e.g. opening/ closing dialogs or clicking between non-modal windows etc. and returns the old and new widget objects.

```py
class addAttributeTableAction(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.app.focusChanged.connect(self.attribute_dialog_opened)

    def __del__(self):
        self.app.focusChanged.disconnect(self.attribute_dialog_opened)

    def attribute_dialog_opened(self, old, new):
        if isinstance(new, QTableView):
            #I don't like the line below but I could't think of a better/quicker way to
            #return the Dialog object from the QTableView object returned by the 'new' parameter
            #of the focusChanged signal
            table_dialog = new.parent().parent().parent().parent()
            toolbar = [c for c in table_dialog.children() if isinstance(c, QToolBar)][0]
            # check if action has already been added to toolbar
            already_exists = [a for a in toolbar.actions() if a.objectName() == 'TestAction']
            if not already_exists:
                new_button = QAction('Test', table_dialog)
                new_button.setObjectName('TestAction')
                toolbar.addAction(new_button)
                new_button.triggered.connect(self.run_action)

    def run_action(self):
        '''Simple method to test action'''
        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        layer.selectByIds([1])

Test = addAttributeTableAction(qApp)
#Uncomment below andcomment above to stop listening for focusChanged signal
#del Test
```

Quick demo:

[image]

Comment: This answer seems the best solution I found so far. I used `evetFilter` but I couldn't get any result. Probably I miss something.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution (QGIS 3.12.2, works perfectly fine under Ubuntu, I saw few QGIS crashes under Windows 10) that gives you access directly to all opened attribute tables dialogs or attribute tables of a specific layer.

Explanations :

- Copy and run this code into the QGIS Python Console Editor
- The code run in another thread, so, you can continue QGIS activities.
- Modify the refresh rate if you need. Here it is 2 seconds.
- If you want to access to attribute tables :

  - `attribute_tables()` returns a list with all opened attribute tables ;
  - `attribute_tables(layer_id)` returns the list of all opened attribute tables of the layer.
- If you want to stop the worker (= background thread), just `worker = None`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject


class Worker(QThread):
    result = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, qgsapp, qgsproject):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.app = qgsapp
        self.qpj = qgsproject

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ats = {
                id(o): [o.objectName()[24:], o]
                for o in self.app.allWidgets()
                if isinstance(o, QDialog)
                and o.objectName()[:24] == "QgsAttributeTableDialog/"
            }
            lyr_at = {}
            for lyrid, dialog in ats.values():
                if lyrid in lyr_at:
                    lyr_at[lyrid].append(dialog)
                else:
                    lyr_at[lyrid] = [dialog]

            self.result.emit(lyr_at)
            sleep(2)  # refresh rate : 2 seconds


class Atat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._dialogs = {}

    @property
    def dialogs(self) -> dict:
        return self._dialogs

    @dialogs.setter
    def dialogs(self, value: dict):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            self._dialogs = value


def attribute_tables(layer_id: str = None) -> list:
    global ATINST
    if not layer_id:
        return [d for ld in ATINST.dialogs.values() for d in ld]
    elif layer_id in ATINST.dialogs:
        return ATINST.dialogs[layer_id]

    return []


app = QgsApplication.instance()
qpj = QgsProject.instance()
ATINST = Atat()
worker = Worker(app, qpj)
worker.result.connect(
    lambda new_at: setattr(ATINST, 'dialogs', new_at)
)
worker.start()
```